# How to disable pin/passphrase timeout in GPG, so I don't have to enter it for every commit, on Windows 10? There's no `gpg.conf` or `gpg-agent.conf`

Tags: git, windows-10, gnupg, gpg-signature

I've looked for help around this everywhere and disected several stackoverflow threads but they all seem to be out of date or simply not valid to windows 10.

The most promising has been this thread which relies on --pinentry-mode-loopback but I can't seem to have a correct file as I've tried that command on all .gpg files I have, which are in this list:

[image]

As for gpg agent, this is all I got:

[image]

as for .conf file all I have is an unrelated gradle file.

I'm using git with github as the remote for node projects via VSCode.